# Submit form with jquery, ajax, can't get success callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Alright, I'm pretty close on this, but I need a bit of help getting over the hump. I'm trying to submit a form via AJAX, in a rails app, which sends an email, and then executes some code on success. When I hit enter on my form, the AJAX is working, because I'm getting the email. However, the success code isn't running (nor the error for that matter). I also tried 'complete:' but that didn't work, so I suspect it may be some problem with the default form behavior? Ideas?

Here is the ajax:

```
// AJAX Function to submit email form without refreshing page
$("#contact_me").submit(function(){
    var dataSet = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: dataSet,
        success: function(){
            alert("Sent!");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

And the rails action which it calls:

```
def email_me
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    content = params[:text]

    ContactMailer.first_contact(name, email, content).deliver

    head :ok
end
```

Also, the form itself

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "main", action: "email_me"}, id: "contact_me", remote: "true") do %>
    <div>
        <p><%= label_tag(:name, "Name") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:name) %></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><%= label_tag(:email, "Email") %>
        <%= email_field(:user, :email) %></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><%= label_tag(:text, "What's on your mind?") %></p>
        <%= text_area_tag(:text)%>
    </div>

    <%= submit_tag("Say Hello!")%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really the little things that end up causing the biggest problems. I forgot to wrap the whole function in a function(){..}. Go figure, works great now. Thanks for the help all.

```
$(function(){
    $("#contact_me").submit(function(){
        var dataSet = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: dataSet,
            complete: function(){
                alert("Sent!");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. You should mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Completely random guess so forgive me if it's ridiculous, could it be `render :nothing => true` preventing Rails to fire the callback?

Comment: Tried removing the line, same behavior happens

Answer (score 0):

Your rails app should return JSON. You are ajaxing a JSON request, it should be a JSON response. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, removed the dataType line, so now that shouldn't matter. Same behavior happens tho.

Comment: Hmm, I would add it back in. Use: format.json {render :json => true} in your response. Let me know if that works. I believe it needs a response to fire a callback.

Comment: I just thought of something. What exaclty is the goal of your callback? If you just want a message to confirm to the user that the message was sent. Then use the "complete" method instead of the success.  If you are trying to verify that the message was actually sent by the server, then you should be outputting something from the server to indicate as such...

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering blank json instead, as your JS is expecting a JSON response.

> render :json => {}

Comment: Better yet, remove `dataType: "json"`. Also change `render :nothing => true` to `head :ok` per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-nothing

Comment: Code refactored using @gregates suggestions, but same behavior, success: not happening