# Rails - get id from new record after ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using ajax to submit a form that creates a new record without refreshing the current page, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723501/1162836

This is the ajax from that answer:

```
$('form').submit(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
    }).success(function(json){
        //act on result.
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

How do I then get the id of the newly created record?

Comment: start by doing a `alert(json)` inside your success event handler. If your controller respond with JSON, it should outputs the object updated.

Comment: I couldn't get the success function to work - tried wrapping the above code in a function as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17240354/1162836 - but that causes the page to refresh on submit (and still no success alert).

Comment: Okay, messed around with it a little and it does work if I add `complete: function(json){alert(json);},` but the result is `[object Object]`. Is that useful?

Comment: before the alert, parse the response as JSON: `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);` and then do a `alert(data);` - or better, use `console.log(data)`, it should show you the informations of the updated object. Documentation for jQuery.parseJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Hmm, now it says `null`.

Comment: Okay, got it figured out - your first comment was the clue, I had not added `render json` to the create method in the controller.